# MYSQL/php - Procedure question

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am querying a table that has classified ads in it.  I need to have find all of the ads that are current (from between now and their expiration date), but all I want is the category that they are in and how many there are from each category.  Here is what I have but can't get it to work.

```
SELECT AdType.AdTypeID,
       AdType.AdDescription,
       Class_Ads.AdTypeID,
       Class_Ads.DateSubmitted
FROM Class_Ads
INNER JOIN AdType ON Class_Ads.AdTypeID = AdType.AdTypeID
WHERE Class_Ads.DateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() 
      AND (date_add(Class_Ads.DateSubmitted,INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY AdType.AdDescription
```

What I want the outcome to look like is:

```
category1 (5 ads)
category2 (2 ads)
etc.
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd suggest you store an expiry time as well as a submitted time - You know that at some point in future, someone will suggest 3 month ads for a bigger fee (or similar)

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT AdType.AdDescription, COUNT(*)
      FROM Class_ads
INNER JOIN AdType ON Class_Ads.AdTypeID = AdType.AdTypeID
     WHERE Class_Ads.DateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() 
       AND (date_add(Class_Ads.DateSubmitted,INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
  GROUP BY AdType.AdDescription
```

That should do the trick